# Simple script to insert data

Tags: beginner, sql, t-sql

This is a simple script which inserts data into a couple of tables. I'm very new to SQL so any feeback, of any kind, would be much appreciated!

```
DECLARE 
      @Model_ID INT
    , @ModelVersion VARCHAR(10)
    , @ExistsInDM INT
    , @IsActive BIT

SET @ModelVersion = '2.46.7' -- new version number
SET @IsActive = '1'

SELECT  @Model_ID = Model_ID
FROM    [sch_AM].[tblDMModelVersion] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   [ModelVersion] = @ModelVersion                  

IF @Model_ID IS NULL 
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO [sch_AM].[tblDMModelVersion]
            (  [ModelVersion]
                ,[IsActive]
                            )
    VALUES  ( @ModelVersion
                ,@IsActive
                )

    EXECUTE sch_AM.usp_GetActiveModel_ID @ModelVersion, @Model_ID OUTPUT

    SELECT @ExistsInDM = COUNT(Model_ID) 
    FROM [sch_AM].[tblDMModelToTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE Model_ID = @Model_ID

    IF @ExistsInDM = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [sch_AM].[tblDMModelToTable]
            SELECT
                    @Model_ID
                    ,[Table_ID]
                    ,[TableVersion]
                    ,[UserViewable]
                    ,[TableRequiredByModel]
            FROM [sch_AM].[tblDMModelToTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE Model_ID = 1
        END
END

SELECT * FROM [sch_AM].[tblDMModelVersion] WHERE Model_ID = @Model_ID
SELECT * FROM [sch_AM].[tblDMModelToTable] WHERE Model_ID = @Model_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just 1 will work here.  It will do a cast to 1

```
SET @IsActive = 1
```

You can also assign in the declare

```
DECLARE 
      @Model_ID INT
    , @ModelVersion VARCHAR(10) = 'lasdf'
    , @ExistsInDM INT
    , @IsActive BIT = 1


SELECT  @Model_ID = Model_ID
FROM    [sch_AM].[tblDMModelVersion] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   [ModelVersion] = @ModelVersion
```

Above will get the last value read.

```
with (nolock)
```

Is typically not advised.